# More performant canvas draw code?

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine

In performance testing my draw code is taking up a large % of processing. I'm calling this every frame when I need to draw.

```
BoardDisplay.prototype.drawCursor = function (client, context, vx, vy) {
    context.beginPath();
    var size = 25;
    context.arc(vx, vy, 0.5 * size, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    var colors = ["white", "red", "blue", "green", "purple"];
    context.fillStyle = colors[this.marble];
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    context.beginPath();
    var cursorRadius = 5;
    context.moveTo(vx - cursorRadius, vy);
    context.lineTo(vx + cursorRadius, vy);
    context.moveTo(vx, vy - cursorRadius);
    context.lineTo(vx, vy + cursorRadius);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
};
```

I could extract those constants into values on the prototype. Is there another way I could make this more performant?

I understand `React.js` only updates "as needed", but I'm drawing the canvas here, not divs. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: How often are you redrawing your canvas?  If you're doing it in a loop, can you add your loop code?

Answer (score 0):

General solutions are:

- are you sure you want to use canvas (instead of svg, webgl, server image generation, ...) ?
- reduce canvas size if possible (less pixels = less work)
- handle 'diff' yourself for canvas
- use layering

For more details see this excellent article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Comment: I've lowered my framerate since it doesn't need fast updates, that helps. Size has to be as big as it is. I'm not familiar with diffing, I'll check that article!

Comment: You may also double the draw size (bigger pixels, but much faster). Most old games do this. For example 320x240 but show it as 640x480.